# Issue with accepts_nested_attributes_for while using authlogic_oauth

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authlogic, authlogic-oauth

I have the following models:

```
class Merchant
  acts_as_authentic
  has_one :store
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :store
end

class Store
  belongs_to :merchant
end
```

I am using authlogic_oauth gem for Twitter authentication. While registration I save the Merchant and the Store model. If I disable the oauth authentication both models are saved. When ever I enable the oauth authentication only Merchant instance is saved.

After spending some time looking at the authlogic_oauth gem code I think found the culprit. The authlogic_oauth gem stores the ActiveRecord attributes in the session during oauth calls. But it does not store the attributes of the associations.

```
# authlogic_oauth : lib/authlogic_oauth/acts_as_authentic.rb
def save(perform_validation = true, &block)
  if perform_validation && block_given? && redirecting_to_oauth_server?
    # My comment: Any nested attributes are not saved in the session
    session_class.controller.session[:authlogic_oauth_attributes] = attributes.reject!{|k, v| v.blank?}
    # some code
  end
  # some code
end
```

I can hack the gem code but I am wondering if there is a better solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I addressed the issue by saving Store attributes temporarily in the session for the duration of Oauth calls.I hope there is a better way to address this issue.

```
class MerchantsController < ApplicationController
 before_filter :init_nested_attr

 def create
   @merchant = Merchant.new(params[:merchant])
   @merhcant.save do |result|
     #some code
   end
 end

private
 def init_nested_attr
   if session[:authlogic_oauth_attributes]
     params[:merchant] = session[:authlogic_oauth_attributes]
     params[:merchant][:store_attributes] = session.delete(:authlogic_oauth_store_attributes)
   else
     session[:authlogic_oauth_store_attributes] = params[:merchant][:store_attributes]
   end
 end
end
```